# Android studio how to determine which layout is displayed

Tags: android

Lets assume that I have a pretty big Android app and run test build on device (emulator or real) and go to some specific screen.

Is there any way to determine which screen is currently displayed on device? I.e. I'm on `MainActivity` screen with `activity_main.xml` layout and I want to find there this info is displayed.

I couldn't find such thing in Logcat.

Comment: in `onCreate` of your `Activity`/`Fragment` , you can log your class name

Comment: I could do so, but the problem is that I don't know activity's class either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer in a pretty unexpected place.

You can track your displayed screens via Chrome.

Go to

chrome://inspect/#devices -> inspect your device -> elements.

There you can find your layout elements, activities, fragments etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep a unique tag name with the class Name as given below

```
private static final String TAG = "UniqueName" + EachCalss.class.getSimpleName();
```

while debugging time search with uniqueName

Comment: I could do so, but the problem is that I don't know activity's class either.